# Delegate is NULL

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a table view from where i send a request the data from the url. I am able to fetch the data but i want to use delegate to send the data back to table view.

The problem is when i assign my **self.delegate** it contains a value but when i am trying to send back the data **self.delegate** become 0x000000.

**In viewcontroller.m**

```
GNRequestManager *request = [[GNRequestManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
```

**In GNRequestManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GNDownloadManager.h"

@protocol RequestManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didReceiveData:(NSMutableArray *)data;

@end


@interface GNRequestManager : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<RequestManagerDelegate> delegate;

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<RequestManagerDelegate>)inDelegate;

- (void)requestWithURL:(NSString *)urlString;

-(void)didReceiveResponse:(NSMutableArray *)downloadData;



@end
```

**In GNRequestManager.m**

```
-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<RequestManagerDelegate>)inDelegate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        self.delegate = inDelegate; // **self.delegate has a value**

    }

    return self;
}



- (void)didReceiveResponse:(NSMutableArray *)downloadData // Fetch the data in downloadData

{

    if(!itemArray)
    {
        itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    itemArray = downloadData;

    [self.delegate didReceiveData:itemArray]; // **self.delegate does not contain any value**

}
```

Comment: Might be GNRequestManager *request get released if it is not retained.

Comment: Where is the 'delegate' declaration?

Comment: add the interface for your manager. and I assume delegate is weak (it should be) and your VC is deallocated

Comment: delegate declaration is done in GNRequestManager.h            @property (nonatomic, weak) id<RequestManagerDelegate> delegate;

Comment: @AnkitAngra, can you post the header file entirely?

Comment: #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GNDownloadManager.h"

protocol RequestManagerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didReceiveData:(NSMutableArray *)data;

end






interface GNRequestManager : NSObject

property (nonatomic, weak) id<RequestManagerDelegate> delegate;

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<RequestManagerDelegate>)inDelegate;

- (void)requestWithURL:(NSString *)urlString;

-(void)didReceiveResponse:(NSMutableArray *)downloadData;



end

Comment: I have deleted @'s because website was not allowing me to do so..

Comment: Edit your question to add additional code -- don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have this problem once. As far as I can understand, you are storing your `delegate` as a property with `weak` modifier. That means that your `GNRequestManager` doesn't increase reference count of your delegate object.
If you are creating delegate object like:

```
GNDelegateObject *delegate = [GNDelegateObject new];
GNRequestManager *manager = [[GNRequestManager alloc] initWithDelegate:delegate];
```

delegate object will be released.

You should hold a strong reference to your delegate object somewhere else (not in `GNRequestManager`).

UPD: You've updated the question, that the delegate is set like:

```
GNRequestManager *request = [[GNRequestManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self];
```

where `self` is an instance of `UIViewController` subclass.

Is this view controller still in view controller hierarchy? Maybe, you've dismissed/popped it so that it is deallocated now?

Comment: Emphasis on strong reference "somewhere else". An object having a strong reference to a delegate will often lead to a retain cycle. If all of that doesn't make sense, time to read Apple's documentation.

Comment: @gnasher729 "somewhere else" means outside of the GNRequestManager. Edited the answer, thank you.

Comment: I agree with @Nikita. It is obviously that `inDelegate` is getting released and nilled out, because the `delegate` prop. is weak.